# Get complete subfolder-structure from library/folder

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, folder, subfolders

I need a list of all folders including all their subfolders.
The default "Get Folder" action in Power Automate gives me only the first level of subfolders but not the complete structure.

How do I retrieve the complete (sub-)folder structure and save it to a CSV file?

Answer (score 1):

This may not be exactly what you're looking for, but it might be enough to point you in the right direction.

You can use the **Send an HTTP request to SharePoint** action to get all the folders in a list or library. Set these property values:

**Uri**: `_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('[List Name]')/Items?$select=*,FileDirRef&$filter=FSObjType eq 1`

**Headers**: `{ "Accept": "application/json;odata=nometadata" }`

Replace [List Name] with the name of your list or library.

The `FileDirRef` field in the select is the server relative URL for the folder. The `FSObjType eq 1` filter tell SharePoint you only want folders.

[image: Send an HTTP request to SharePoint action]

You can then use a **Select** action to extract the information you want from the response from the **Send an HTTP request to SharePoint** action.

Use the following expressions:

**From**: `body('Send_an_HTTP_request_to_SharePoint')['value']`

**Map - Title**: `item()['Title']`

**Map - ServerRelativeUrl**: `item()['FileDirRef']`

[image: Select action]

The output from the **Select** action should be an array that looks something like the JSON you see below. You could use this information to populate the CSV file.

```
[
    {
        "Title": "Folder 1",
        "ServerRelativeUrl": "/sites/demo3/Lists/Folder Test"
    },
    {
        "Title": "Folder 2",
        "ServerRelativeUrl": "/sites/demo3/Lists/Folder Test"
    },
    {
        "Title": "Folder 11",
        "ServerRelativeUrl": "/sites/demo3/Lists/Folder Test/Folder 1"
    },
    {
        "Title": "Folder 12",
        "ServerRelativeUrl": "/sites/demo3/Lists/Folder Test/Folder 1"
    },
    {
        "Title": "Folder 121",
        "ServerRelativeUrl": "/sites/demo3/Lists/Folder Test/Folder 1/Folder 12"
    }
]
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: This looks great! But now it throws an error and stops the Flow:
"A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (*)."

Comment: I assume you're getting that error from the Send an HTTP request to SharePoint action. If so, what value are you using for Uri an Headers? It could be that one of them is malformed.

Comment: I used your code:
_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Dokumente')/Items$select=*,FileDirRef&$filter=FSObjType eq 1
where 'Dokumente' is the library name.

Comment: Sorry, my answer missed the `?` between `/Items` and `$select`. The full URL should be `_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Dokumente')/Items?$select=*,FileDirRef&$filter=FSObjType eq 1`. I updated the answer accordingly.